# Alter values available in node reference field based on term reference

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type structure as mentioned below,

- Content Type

  - Field Collection

    - Term Reference
    - Node Reference
    - Text Field

What I want to accomplish is, As I select the Term Reference value; the available values in node reference field with auto complete widget should only be of those nodes that have the term reference value assigned.

FYI The field collection will have multiple values.

Comment: Node reference or entity reference?  Which module are you using (References of Entity Reference)?

Comment: I am using node reference (Reference Module) as of now, but I am flexible with the field as the site is currently under development. And there are no restrictions as such. Just the task is to be accomplished

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I am late to answer your question :), but I hope this will help someone.

Using [Dynamic dependent fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf) you can achive this, but it support `Entity Reference`field not `Node Reference`
[Documentation for Dynamic dependent fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2532790)